# Use WinRT API in netstandard2.0 library referenced by .NET 5.0 with IsOSPlatform check

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, interop, .net-5

We are in the process of updating our `netcoreapp3.1` libraries and programs to `net5.0`. These libraries are referencing one `netstandard2.0` library which uses WinRT if supported via a NuGet reference to `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts`.
This is checked via `RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)`.
If I now use this library from `net5.0` and execute the part using WinRT I get the following exception (executed on Win 10 20H2 with .NET 5.0.2):

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform. (0x80131539)

If I read up on the breaking changes for `net5.0` I get that this package is no longer needed/supported and to use WinRT you should target e.g. `net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0`. But I would like to keep the library platform-agnostic as `netstandard2.0` and keep using the `IsOSPlatform`-switch, as other parts of the library are also used on Linux or using `net471`.

**How can I make this work with `net5.0` as we did with `netcoreapp3.1`?**

Comment: Cross-Post with GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48102

Comment: a netstandard library that hard references Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts is already a strange design, since it's not platform-agnostic. Why do you need netstandard in the first place?  "you can think of .NET 5 as .NET Standard vNext" https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-future-of-net-standard/

Comment: @SimonMourier The rest of the library is platform-agnostic (access library for a LibUSB based device), we just do some additional checks on windows, because of some known issues which use the `Windows.Devices` namespace. It did work fine on Windows and Linux with `netcoreapp3.1`.

Comment: With .NET 5 out, netstandard is just interesting for Mono and Xamarin (and it will change in the future). Maybe you could reorganize/split your components (agnostic => netstandard, non agnostic => .NET 5). I had to do a lot of these these days (ie: dropping netstandard). There are a number of no-way-back issues or things that just don't work like they used to for 20 years or so, with .NET 5.

Comment: @SimonMourier Already thought about that and also think it's the way to go. `netstandard` is because it is a public library and I do not want to block `net4x` from using it...